# Match filtering return unexpected results Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, filtering

I'm starting in Neo4j and I'm doing the GraphAcademy intermediate cypher course.

The use case is to find the number of movies released in a the UK.

The problem is that I do get different quantities for the UK depending if I filter out movies that don't have UK in the countries list with `where 'UK' in m.countries` and get 893 against 1386 if I omit the filter.

```
MATCH (m:Movie)                          // get all movie nodes
//where 'UK' in m.countries              // filter out those not released in the UK 
unwind m.countries as countries          // extract countries into separate rows
with m, trim(countries) as country       // trim out unwanted spaces 
with country, collect(m.title) as movies // regroup movies into a list

return country, movies, size(movies)     // return country, list, movie count
```

I was expecting to get the same list of movies for UK whether I use the filter or not, and I was expecting different movies lists for other countries..as nodes without uk in the countries list were not retrieved if the filter is used..

If a movie doesn't have UK in the countries list shouldn't get included in the UK movies list anyways correct?

Comment: how can I get a copy of the database Movie with countries property? My Movies database does not have a countries. Thanks.

Comment: that's correct.. however it seems you have commented out the where part of the query?

Comment: @jose_bacoy I'm taking the Intermediate Cypher queries Course at https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/courses/cypher-intermediate-queries/5-pipelining-queries/10-c1-unwind/

Comment: @TomažBratanič yes I commented out the where part of the query to show that without it I get different values.. with it I get 893 movies under the UK language, with it it I get 1386 movies under the UK language

Comment: 893 is the wrong answer

Comment: If you omit the filter you get 893 , with filter you get 1386 is that accurate?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor, hi, no it's the other way round.. with the filter I get 893,  without I get 1386 movies with UK in the m.countries property.

Comment: Then it's fine right. Without the filter if you get 1386, then not all 1386 movies will have UK in the countries list

Comment: The query I posted groups movies under the country,. Under UK I get different results, as mentioned above, depending on if I apply a filter or not. This shouldn't  happen for the uk label as the uk value is present. But somehow filtering for the uk value alters the result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the data, some of the movies contain `UK` as a country, and some contain  `UK` as a country. That's why the results are differing. Try this:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)                       
where 'UK' in m.countries OR ' UK' in m.countries               
unwind m.countries as countries          
with m, trim(countries) as country 
with country, collect(DISTINCT m.title) as movies
return country, size(movies)
```

Now, you should get same count for `UK` with or without filter.